# How to add captcha on Civicrm contribution pages and Events pages

Tags: civievent, contribution-page, recaptcha

Can any one help me configure `captcha` on Contribution pages and events. I can only find recaptcha settings here: `example.com/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1`

Comment: Doesn't work. I just tried it on 4.4. Why am I not surprised.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3576)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3576)

Comment: @GaryWells why are you working on 4.4 instead of 4.7 or 4.6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include a Profile in your Contribution Pages and Events and include recaptcha for it.

On newer sites via civicrm/admin/setting/recaptcha?reset=1 where you can also Force on all Contribution pages (and hence skip the below steps about setting on Profiles)

On older sites set up your reCAPTCHA keys visit Administer > System Settings > Misc (/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1)

Then to set it in your Profile visit

Administer -> Customise Data and Screens -> Profiles

1. Click on settings link for the profile added on your contribution page or event.
2. Expand the Advanced Settings tab
3. Enable the `Include reCAPTCHA?` checkbox and Save.

Comment: Make sure to log out or use an Incognito window to test, or the reCaptcha won't show up.