# Adding Captcha to the forms

Tags: forms, recaptcha

Hello I am trying to add captcha to both my donation page and my membership sign up page. I found the instructions to go to administer>customize data>profiles. I have added captcha to name and address, supporter profile and your resisgration info and it doesnt show up on the acutal form.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am using wordpress and version 4.6.15

Comment: Just to be sure, you've added the profile(s) in question to your donation page and membership sign up page?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Wordpress, but in certain instances in Drupal, logged-in users can automatically bypass a captcha. Are you looking at those pages logged in as administrator or logged out?

Comment: Also just to check the basics since you don't mention it. You have set up your recaptcha access keys? instructions at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/how-to-add-captcha-on-civicrm-contribution-pages-and-events-pages

Comment: The logging out thing worked. Thanks man was that frustrating!

Comment: @Gary Wells You can post your comment as an answer and it will help people who come after you!

Answer (score 6):

Solution was for the user to test this logged out.

Comment: Yeah, this got me too! Glad I found this.